# How do I implement age screening measures and self-certified ad SDK to my android app?

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, ads, google-play-console

I am trying to make my app available to a wider audience so my app has ads which will show to people of all ages including kids but for that to work I need to implement age screening measures and self-certified ad sdk but I don't understand how exactly I'm suppose to do this. I looked up age screening measures and self-cerified ad SDK but I can't find any actual instructions on how to do this, can someone help me out on how I'm suppose to do this?